# How to express a negative power in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, staking, safemath, curve, bonding-curves

Trying to express y=2^x where x is a negative number. As Solidity does not support negative powers, is there another way to express this?

Thanks for any tips!

We are trying to create a decay formula

[image]

Comment: You can use division to implement that: y = A * B ^(-x) = A / B^x . Both div and exp with positive power are available.

Comment: @minhhn2910 thank you, we will try this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To implement a decay formula:

1. you should use int256 as signed integers for using negative exponent powers
2. You can use exponents as hardcoded values if you're using `**` which denotes exponents so you would have to write as `a ** -10`
3. If you're making a formula I recommend using the `PRBMath` library for using the `.exp()` function for exponents and math calculation

Here's the link to the PRBMath library: https://github.com/PaulRBerg/prb-math

Comment: Many thanks for the steps/ suggestions Sharoz!